# Retrieving a Many-t-Many Field value with django-rest-framework serializers

Tags: django-rest-framework, many-to-many, django-serializer

I want to retrieve manytomany field value in my serializer.
My Project Model is as

```
 class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    addedby = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='projectadder')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    projecttype = models.ForeignKey(ProjectType,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='projecttpye')
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    pros = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    cons = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    team = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    supervisor = models.ManyToManyField(Supervisor)
    cosupervisor = models.ManyToManyField(CoSupervisor)
    technology = models.ManyToManyField(Technology)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    teamleader = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='teamleader')
    proposal = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    buyers = models.ManyToManyField(Buyer)
    reviews = models.ManyToManyField(Review)
    requirements = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectRequirement)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectImage)
```

My serializer is as:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projecttype = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='projecttype.name')
    addedby = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='addedby.username')
    teamleader = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='teamleader.username')
    # team = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='team')
    class Meta:
        model= Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

It is retrieving ForiegnKey elements sucessfuly but not retriving ManytoMany Field Values?

Comment: Note: Many to Many Field that I want to retrieve is User BuiltIn Model.

Comment: But If I use 
team = UserSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
It retrieve all fields from this model, but I just want username.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the serializers for those ManyToManyFields.
For example, the model has a many to many relationship with the `Supervisor` model.
So you can set the `supervisors` field in the `ProjectSerializer`.

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    supervisors = SupervisorSerializer(many = True, read_only = True, fields=(...))

    class Meta:
        model= Project
        fields = (..., 'supervisors',)
```

In order to set fields parameters, you can customize `__init__` function.

```
class SupervisorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        set_fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if set_fields is not None:
            allowed = set(set_fields )
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

You need to add the serializers for all the many to many fields.
Hope it could help.

Comment: In this way, it retrieve all the fields from supervisor model.

Comment: So isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: I just want some specific field. I already have a serializer for SUpervisor. 
So it means I have to write another serializer for some specific fields that I will use in Project serializer?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.

Comment: Or you can customize `__init__` function. I'll add that part into my answer.

Comment: fields = (..., 'supervisors',)
what to put this "," after supervisor as there is no field after supervisor?

Comment: I added. please check it again.